# Multiple session scoped backing bean instances in JSF portlet environment

Tags: richfaces, facelets, portlet, ajax4jsf

I am developing for an external environment running a `JBoss Portal Server (2.7.1)`.

The product is a Facelets-portlet using SEAM components as backing beans (`JSF 1.2`, `SEAM 2.1.1.GA`, `Richfaces 3.3.1.GA`).

My problem: The backing bean is SEAM session-scoped (`@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)`). But the moment I am calling any of the methods via `A4J` I'll get a new instance, as if there were different sessions involved. All "simple" requests (`h:commandButton`) will be handled by the "original" instance, all `A4J` requests are handled by the "new" instance.

I'd really need the same instance to implement a working workflow. Is this known behaviour and I got the concept wrong, or is it possible misconfiguration, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a matter of fact I realized this is kind of "works as designed" in the `pre-2.0.0 JBoss-Portletbridge`. The `ActionURLs` do not get rendered as Portlet-URLs but are calling the Faces-Servlet directly. Portletbridge 2.0.0 and up render those URLs as Portlet-URLs, the backing bean is always the same instance.